# Upload file in a specified google drive with google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive REST API. Using this app I can upload the file to Google Drive. But I faced some technical problem.

1. Is it possible to upload files to a specified Google Drive?
2. Is it possible to fix the access code of Google Drive?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet. Kindly specify "technical problems" faced by the Error messages to clarify the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

It is the access token that tells Drive which account it should operate on. So read and understand OAuth and you're good to go.